# .getGuestList returning "EventGuest" instead of list of attendees

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, events

I have tried to fix the following script using codes provided on these forums but nothing has worked so far, I am using the following script to create a list of all the meetings on the calendar but it will not display guests:

```
function importGoogleCalendar() { 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendarId = sheet.getRange('B1').getValue().toString(); 
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
 
  // Set filters
  var startDate = sheet.getRange('B2').getValue();
  var endDate = sheet.getRange('B3').getValue();
  var searchText = sheet.getRange('B4').getValue();
 
  // Print header
  var header = [["Title", "Description", "Start", "End", "Ubicación", "Participantes"]];
  var range = sheet.getRange("A6:F6");
  range.setValues(header);
  range.setFontWeight("bold")
 
  // Get events based on filters
  var events = (searchText == '') ? calendar.getEvents(startDate, endDate) : calendar.getEvents(startDate, endDate, {search: searchText});
 
  // Display events 
  for (var i=0; i<events.length; i++) {
    var row = i+7;
    
    var details = [[events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getDescription(), events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getEndTime(), events[i].getLocation(), events[i].getGuestList(), ]];
      
    range = sheet.getRange(row,1,1,6);
    range.setValues(details);
 
    // Format the Start and End columns
    var cell = sheet.getRange(row, 3);
    cell.setNumberFormat('mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm');
    cell = sheet.getRange(row, 4);
    cell.setNumberFormat('mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm');

   
  }
}
```

Comment: check the [guestStatus](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/guest-status) of every guest to find attendees

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- I think that the reason for your current issue of `.getGuestList returning "EventGuest" instead of list of attendees` is due to that the method of `getGuestList` of Class CalendarEvent returns `CalendarApp.EventGuest[]`. In this case, the name of Class like `EventGuest` is used. If you want to retrieve the email address and the status, it is required to use the methods of `getEmail` and `getGuestStatus`.
- In your script, it seems that `setValues` is used in a loop. In this case, the process cost becomes high. [Ref (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)
- `var startDate = sheet.getRange('B2').getValue(); var endDate = sheet.getRange('B3').getValue(); var searchText = sheet.getRange('B4').getValue()` can be modified to `var [[startDate], [endDate], [searchText]] = sheet.getRange('B2:B4').getValues();`.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function importGoogleCalendar() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendarId = sheet.getRange('B1').getValue().toString();
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);

  // Set filters
  var [[startDate], [endDate], [searchText]] = sheet.getRange('B2:B4').getValues();

  // Print header
  var header = ["Title", "Description", "Start", "End", "Ubicación", "Participantes"];

  // Get events based on filters
  var events = (searchText == '') ? calendar.getEvents(startDate, endDate) : calendar.getEvents(startDate, endDate, { search: searchText });

  // Display events
  var values = [header, ...events.map(e => [e.getTitle(), e.getDescription(), e.getStartTime(), e.getEndTime(), e.getLocation(), e.getGuestList().map(f => `${f.getEmail()}(status ${f.getGuestStatus().toString()})`).join(",")])];
  sheet.getRange(6, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  sheet.getRange("A6:F6").setFontWeight("bold");
  if (values.length == 1) return;
  sheet.getRange(7, 3, values.length - 1, 2).setNumberFormat('mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm');
}
```

- When this script is run, the guest list is put into cells "F7:F" like `emailAddreess(status ###),emailAddreess(status ###),,,`.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [getGuestList()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#getguestlist)
- [getEmail()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/event-guest#getEmail())
- [getGuestStatus()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/event-guest#getGuestStatus())

Comment: Thank you!, that worked, it retuned the emails and invite response, no names but it will do. I will study the script you provided and try to figure out how it works.

Answer (score 0):

**The guest has indicated they are attending**

Check the guestStatus of every guest to get those that are attendees

Change this:

```
var details = [[events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getDescription(), events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getEndTime(), events[i].getLocation(), events[i].getGuestList() ]];
```

to this:

```
var details = [[events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getDescription(), events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getEndTime(), events[i].getLocation(), events[i].getGuestList().filter(g => g.getGuestStatus() == CalendarApp.GuestStatus.YES) ]];
```

- [getGuestStatus()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/event-guest#getgueststatus)
- [GuestStatus Enum](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/guest-status)